# SQL server: Looking for solution to convert columns values/data to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a scenario where I need to convert column values to rows. As you see below I have a table name Test and a column named 'value' and I want the data in that column into rows. I am using SQL Server. Can you help me with the T-SQL script to achieve the below? Apologies if anything is missing

Original

| Value |
| --- |
| 0130509667,0130509791,0130509824,0130509811,0130503549,0130503547,0130509323,0130509320,0130509145,0130509315 |

[image: Please see the raw data]

Output

| Value |
| --- |
| 0130509667 |
| 0130509791 |
| 0130509824 |
| 0130509811 |
| 0130503549 |
| 0130503547 |
| 0130509323 |
| 0130509320 |
| 0130509145 |
| 0130509315 |

[image: Expected Output]

Please advise and let me know if this is possible. Thank you

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @InString VARCHAR(200);
SET @InString='0130509667,0130509791,0130509824,0130509811,0130503549,0130503547,0130509323,0130509320,0130509145,0130509315';
SELECT VALUE FROM string_split(@InString,',');
```

Answer (score 0):

in sql server 2016 + :

```
select y.value from tablename x
cross apply STRING_SPLIT(x.value,',') y
```